# ITrustFrameworkPolicyCollectionPage "Can not be resolved to a type"

Tags: java, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy, azure-sdk

I am trying to use Graph APIs to get list of **"Azure B2C AD TrustFrameworkPolicy"** in Java

These are my dependencies in the POM

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.microsoft.graph</groupId>
            <artifactId>microsoft-graph</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.microsoft.graph</groupId>
            <artifactId>microsoft-graph-core</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.microsoft.graph</groupId>
            <artifactId>microsoft-graph-auth</artifactId>
            <version>0.2.0</version>
        </dependency>
```

I have **clientId, secret and b2ctenant**

I am creating an authentication provider :

```
 ClientCredentialProvider authProvider = 
            new ClientCredentialProvider(clientId,
                    scopes,
                    clientSecret,
                    b2cTenantId,
                    endpoint);
```

And using the auth provider in the graph service client,

```
    IGraphServiceClient graphClient = GraphServiceClient.builder()
                              .authenticationProvider(authProvider)
                              .buildClient();
```

**But when I am using the "ITrustFrameworkPolicyCollectionPage" I am getting error -> Can not be resolved to a type**

```
    ITrustFrameworkPolicyCollectionPage policies = graphClient.trustFramework().policies()
            .buildRequest()
            .get();
```

I am trying to find which maven dependency I missed, or I dont understand why it won't work. Some body please help.

URL https://learn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/graph/api/trustframework-list-trustframeworkpolicies?view=graph-rest-beta&tabs=java

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is broken at the moment...

Instead use this...

```
         ClientCredentialProvider authProvider = 
                 new ClientCredentialProvider(clientId,
                         scopes,
                         clientSecret,
                         b2cTenantId,
                         endpoint); 
        
         OkHttpClient client = HttpClients.createDefault(authProvider);
         Request request = new Request.Builder().url("https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/trustFramework/policies/B2C_1A_User_MigrationClients/$value").build();
         Response response = client.newCall(request).execute();
         System.out.println(response.body().string());
```

This will give you the XML you need which is nothing but the policy.